# Separate workspace per monitor

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, multi-monitor, workspaces

I have a laptop and a separate screen I plugged via HDMI
what I want to do that I use the laptop screen for workspace1 and
external screen for workspace2

this may explain butter:

- each workspace will be "glued" to one monitor.
- when a workspace is selected as "active" it receives the mouse + keyboard inputs.
- windows which have been opened on (active or non-active workspaces) remain displayed on the monitors.

right now I'm using manjaro and Xfce
and AMD GPU

what I find out from my research is that Xfce doesn't support this future
so I want to know what are the best windows managers options to do such a thing and how to do it

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there isn't anything in Linux that handles this very well at the moment (at least as far as independent workspaces on each display).

The good news is, apparently the "Cosmic" DE for PopOS! is looking at it though....
https://github.com/pop-os/cosmic-epoch/issues/53

Unfortunately it's in very early development so will be some time away yet.